# AngularJS closest alternative

Tags: jquery, angularjs

What is the equivalent AngularJS code (controller) for below jQuery code?

```
$("#tabsContainer").closest("[id^='MSOZoneCell_WebPart']").find("span[id^='WebPartCaptionWPQ']").each(function(){
        CEWPID = $(this).attr("id");
    });
    if (CEWPID === ""){
        CEWPID = $("#tabsContainer").closest("[id^='MSOZoneCell_WebPart']").attr("id");
}
```

Comment: You can use Angular.element for it.. But even this code will work. Bad practice though.

Comment: Why can't you do this using angular without using jQuery?

Comment: The control(MSOZoneCell_WebPart) i am trying to get is outside an Iframe. My tabsContainer div is in an Iframe. So SharePoint is not allowing me to access.